# can't send the postString to json

Tags: iphone, objective-c, json

i'm using json Framework for sending the jsonstring. my json post string is

```
{
    "firstName": "string1",
    "lastName": "string2",
    "contactSource": "Leter",
    "permanentAddress": {},
    "deliveryAddress": {},
    "preferredContactTimes": []
}
```

my coding......

```
NSString *postString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"[\"firstName\":\"barani\",\"lastName\":\"Tharn\",\"contactSource\":\"Leter\",\"permanentAddress\":{},\"deliveryAddress\":{},\"preferredContactTimes\":[]]",fName.text,lName.text,contactSource.text,address,address,add];

NSURL *purchaseURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost/Cali/addContact"];
NSMutableURLRequest *request=[NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:purchaseURL];

NSData *requestData = [NSData dataWithBytes:[postString UTF8String] length:[postString length]];

[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [requestData length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setHTTPBody:requestData];//[postString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
NSLog(@"post String :%@",[[NSString alloc] initWithData:requestData encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]);
NSURLConnection *purchaseConn =[[NSURLConnection alloc]
                                initWithRequest:request
                                delegate:self];

if (purchaseConn) {
    NSLog(@"connection!!!");
    webData = [[NSMutableData data] retain];
}
```

and in connection did finish loading

```
NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:webData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"hai:%@",[[NSString alloc] initWithData:webData encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]);

NSDictionary *jsonValue = [jsonString JSONString];
NSLog(@"output:%@",jsonValue);
```

here the `permanentAddress` and `deliveryAddress` also a sub json string adn preferredContactTimes is array

i got the json failed error

> JSONValue failed. Error trace is: (
>       "Error Domain=org.brautaset.JSON.ErrorDomain Code=11 \"Unexpected end of string\" UserInfo=0x4c8d820 {NSLocalizedDescription=Unexpected end of string}"
>   )

please give me the solution

Comment: The format of json is correct. You should just make sure you use the json framework, which you chose, correctly. And provide more details if you really want some support.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is causing your problem, but it is possible especially if your name and other text fields contain non-ASCII characters. You create your NSData as such:

```
NSData *requestData = [NSData dataWithBytes:[postString UTF8String] length:[postString length]];
```

The [postString UTFString] will convert your string into a nil-terminated buffer of bytes. If there are any non-ASCII characters in that string then the length of that buffer will be longer than the number of characters. So if the number of characters in the string is 10, then the number of bytes would be at least 11 (one byte for the nil terminator) and possibly longer.

You then tell NSData that the length of the buffer is equal to the length of the string. So if result of [postString UTF8String] is longer, then you could be getting a truncated buffer and bring to parse it.

Try doing this instead:

```
NSData *requestData = [postString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all i found the problem where it occurs.... i discussed with web service developer. He told that the format i send is correct. But in server side it create junk value automatically because of they create mapping. So they create the new one for me its working fine now...

Thanks